# Possible to deploy WAR via Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: ant, dreamweaver, war, liferay-6

I use Dreamweaver heavily for modifying Liferay templates (Velocity files), and then have to run Apache Ant from Command Prompt to deploy the WAR to Tomcat . Is there anyway I can streamline this process so I can save/deploy straight from Dreamweaver?

I tried to setup a site and specify Tomcat as the local server, but obviously Dreamweaver just tries to push the raw file and does deploy the WAR.. Is there some sort of extension or way I can call Apache Ant from Dreamweaver?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen such an extension, you can search for one at the Adobe Exchange: http://www.adobe.com/go/exchange , however if there isn't one already available, which I suspect there isn't, it would be possible to write one of your own. The following links are for the extending Dreamweaver, and Dreamweaver extensibility APIs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/extend/index.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/apiref/index.html

In this particular case, I believe that you'd need to use an undocumented API call to communicate with an external process (in your case Ant), such as DWfile.runCommandLine() or MM.runCommandLine(). Paul Boon found these and blogged about them and a couple of others here:
http://communitymx.com/blog/index.cfm?newsid=179&blogger=35

Comment: Thanks Danilo, I also had a look at the exchange and couldnt find anything. The link to Paul Boon's article looks especially promising , so Im going to accept your answer

Comment: FWIW: I've used the runCommandLine() methods a number of times, such as communicating out to run a bit of Java, zipping files using 7-Zip, so I think that it can be used for what you're looking to do.